# Reading from an object

Tags: react-native

I want to retrieve the values of marked dates how can I get all the marked dates where marked value is true from this object:

```
  alert(JSON.stringify(this.state._markedDates))
```

---

```
{"2018-09-26":{"marked":true}, "2018-09-27":{"marked":false}, "2018-09-29":{"marked":true}}
```

Expected Result :

```
{"2018-09-26","2018-09-29"}
```

I tried the following but datelist is still empty:

```
    for(var i=0; i<this.state._markedDates.length ; i++)
    {
         if(this.state._markedDates[i].marked == true)
{
this.state.datesList.push(_markedDates[i])
}
    }
```

Comment: You need to add more code, what context are you trying to get these dates? Are you using a for loop, map function, filter function etc. There are loads of ways to do this.

Comment: updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let dates = {
  "2018-09-26":{"marked":true}, 
  "2018-09-27":{"marked":false}, 
  "2018-09-29":{"marked":true}
}
let markedDates=[];

Object.keys(dates).map(date => {
  if(dates[date].marked){ markedDates.push(date)}
})

console.log(markedDates)
```

Answer (score 1):

There are different ways of approaching this, you could filter them for example as below:

```
let dates = ["2018-09-26":{"marked":true}, "2018-09-27":{"marked":false}, "2018-09-29":{"marked":true}];

let filtered = dates.filter( date => {
    if(date.marked === true) {
        return date;
    }
});

// filtered = {"2018-09-26":{"marked":true}, "2018-09-29":{"marked":true}};
```

This is how you can get all of the dates where marked = true.

Then you can do

```
let keyNames = Object.keys(filtered);
console.log(keyNames); // Outputs ["2018-09-26","2018-09-29"]
```

As a for loop

```
let markedDates = [];

for(var i=0; i<this.state._markedDates.length; i++)
{
    if(this.state._markedDates[i].marked === true)
    {
        markedDates.push(_markedDates[i])
    }
}

this.setState({ObjectIWantToSet: markedDates})
```

Comment: thank you! but filtering for some reason is throwing an error. Undefined is not a function dates.filter. I think it only works well with arrays the for loops work though.

Comment: If filter isn't working, this probably means the dates is not an array which was my fault in the code! I have edited it for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
  let dates = []

  let obj = {"2018-09-26":{"marked":true}, "2018-09-27":{"marked":false}, "2018-09-29":{"marked":true}}

for(date in obj)
{
   if(a[date]["marked"])
   {
      dates.push(date)
   }

}
console.log(dates)
```